# the variance matrix get from np.cov() is different from calculation by hand

Tags: python, numpy, covariance

here is the two vector

```
X = [1,3,4,5]
Y = [2,6,2,2]
np.cov(X,Y)
out put is array([[ 2.91666667, -0.33333333],
                  [-0.33333333,  4.        ]])
```

here is the calculation

```
mu(X)=(1+3+4+5)/4=3.25
mu(Y)=(2+6+2+2)/4=3
var[X]=E[(X-mu(X)(X-mu(X)]=8.75
var[Y]=E[(Y-mu(Y)(Y-mu(Y)]=12
cov[X,Y]=E[(X-mu(X)(Y-mu(Y)]=-1
cov[Y,X]=E[(Y-mu(Y)(X-mu(X)]=-1
so the result is array([[8.75, -1],
                        [-1,   12]])
```

It is noticed that the result calculated by hand is just 3 times of the array get from np.cov(X,Y).

My question is why the two matrix is different and does 3 mean anything here or just a 
coincidence

Comment: It looks like you are not dividing by `n-1`,  which is `4-1` in your case, check formula for sample covariance.

Comment: @Akavall i checked my work and yes, i forget. thanks

Comment: @Akavall but i think it should divide 4 here...

Comment: To calculate sample covariance you would divide by `n - 1`, to calculate population covariance you would divide by `n`.